# Accessing variable inside of forEach in mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

I have two queries

1. Suppose if I declared two variables inside a `forEach` like `flowVars.ABC` and `flowVars.DEF`, how can I access those 2 variables outside that `forEach` block?
2. And each variable has a JSON payload, how can I add those 2 variable's data into single JSON payload?

Can anyone assist me? I unable to access the variables inside of foreach and adding 2 JSON.

This is my sample code

```
<flow name="test">
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
                <set-variable variableName="ABC" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="ABC"/>
                <set-variable variableName="DEF" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="DEF"/>
            </scatter-gather>
        </foreach>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.ABC + flowVars.DEF]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="adding 2 vars"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: What version of mule are you using? And what are you trying to do here? Could you please provide input and expected output examples?

Comment: HI Jerney, Mule 3.9 Runtime and i have a bulk of data which i have to upsert into SFDC 2 (A & B)indivudial objects parallel. For that purpose i used scatter gather and post upsert the records, the SFDC respose i mapped with the appropriate ID's there i can filter the failure records.. the entire process in forEach.., here i have two payloads (which have only the A & B failure records only) ., i have to take those 2 JSON payloads and append those and generate into CSV file.

Comment: Here using transformer how can i append those 2 payloads into single payload?? and scatter gather is calling twice 0 & 1 ., i want to make it as a single call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand how scoping works with `foreach`. Any variables set inside the `foreach` scope will NOT be available outside of that scope. However, variables set outside of the `foreach` scope (e.g. a `set-variable` before the `foreach`) will be available inside the `foreach` scope. This should help you get around your issue. I'm taking out the scatter-gather because it really doesn't serve any purpose in your example:

```
<flow name="test">
    <set-variable variableName="ABC value="#[payload] mimeType="application/json" doc:name="ABC"/>
    <set-variable variableName="DEF value="#[payload] mimeType="application/json" doc:name="DEF"/>
    <foreach doc:name="For Each">
        <set-variable variableName="ABC" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="ABC"/>
        <set-variable variableName="DEF" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="DEF"/>
    </foreach>
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars.ABC ++ flowVars.DEF]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="adding 2 vars"/>
</flow>
```

Beyond this, I'm not sure if your code is a simplification or not, but as it stands now there are a couple things that are questionable:

Why are you using a scatter-gather? If you don't really need to do multiple things asynchronously (like making calls to multiple services), it's just a complication in your code. Setting two vars doesn't qualify, in my opinion.

What is your code supposed to do? From my perspective it looks like you're just setting the payload to a duplicate of the last element in the original payload. If so you could just do this in a transformer:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
if (not isEmpty(payload))
  payload[-1] ++ payload[-1]
else
  []
```